# SELECT QUERY to get the assistance of employees, in a range of hours

Tags: php, mysql, select, range, hour

I'm getting some troubles making a `QUERY` like this:

I have this table, **mt_reporteradial**:

[image]

I need the follow result in `SELECT QUERY`, establishing a range of hours (for ex.: between 11h and 15h):

```
idmtpersonalr               11           12           13           14           15
      3                     -            -            -            X            -
      5                     -            -            -            X            X
      7                     -            -            -            X            X
```

where `indicador='S'` means the `'X'` in the result, and `ìndicador='N'`means the `'-'`

Is it possible just with MySQL? or i need to make it with php too?

Greetings.

**Edited:** I have the answer:

My updated table:

[image]

The `QUERY`:

```
SELECT
    distinct(idmtpersonalr),
CASE (SELECT indicador FROM mt_reporteradial WHERE idmtpersonalr = m.idmtpersonalr AND hora='13' AND fecha='2014-02-10')
        WHEN 'S' THEN 'X'
        WHEN 'N' THEN '-'
    END as 13_hr,
    CASE (SELECT indicador FROM mt_reporteradial WHERE idmtpersonalr = m.idmtpersonalr AND hora='14' AND fecha='2014-02-10')
        WHEN 'S' THEN 'X'
        WHEN 'N' THEN '-'
    END as 14_hr,
    CASE (SELECT indicador FROM mt_reporteradial WHERE idmtpersonalr = m.idmtpersonalr AND hora='15' AND fecha='2014-02-10')
        WHEN 'S' THEN 'X'
        WHEN 'N' THEN '-'
    END as 15_hr,
    CASE (SELECT indicador FROM mt_reporteradial WHERE idmtpersonalr = m.idmtpersonalr AND hora='16' AND fecha='2014-02-10')
        WHEN 'S' THEN 'X'
        WHEN 'N' THEN '-'
    END as 16_hr
FROM
    mt_reporteradial m
```

Comment: What if there are multiple (or no) records for the same `(idmtpersonalr, hora)` combination?  What if the values of `indicador` conflict?  How would such matters be resolved?  In general, pivoting data in this fashion is a presentational matter best left to the presentation layer of your application and not to the database layer.  However, it can be done (using grouping and conditional operators over aggregate functions).

Comment: Programatically, there aren't conflicts ( duplicates rows for `idmtpersonalr`, `hora`, and `fecha` ) because i make a condition when data is insert in this table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something Like this might work:

```
SELECT
    distinct(idmtpersonalr),
    CASE (SELECT indicador FROM mt_reporteradial WHERE idmtpersonalr = m.idmtpersonalr AND hora='11')
        WHEN 'S' THEN 'X'
        WHEN 'N' THEN '-'
    END CASE as 11_hr,
    CASE (SELECT indicador FROM mt_reporteradial WHERE idmtpersonalr = m.idmtpersonalr AND hora='12')
        WHEN 'S' THEN 'X'
        WHEN 'N' THEN '-'
    END CASE as 12_hr,
    CASE (SELECT indicador FROM mt_reporteradial WHERE idmtpersonalr = m.idmtpersonalr AND hora='13')
        WHEN 'S' THEN 'X'
        WHEN 'N' THEN '-'
    END CASE as 13_hr,
    CASE (SELECT indicador FROM mt_reporteradial WHERE idmtpersonalr = m.idmtpersonalr AND hora='14')
        WHEN 'S' THEN 'X'
        WHEN 'N' THEN '-'
    END CASE as 14_hr,
    CASE (SELECT indicador FROM mt_reporteradial WHERE idmtpersonalr = m.idmtpersonalr AND hora='15')
        WHEN 'S' THEN 'X'
        WHEN 'N' THEN '-'
    END CASE as 15_hr
FROM
    mt_reporteradial m
WHERE
    fecha = '2014-02-10'
```

Comment: I got it modifying this `query`, i'll edit the question with the answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome! But please note that the query is extremely inefficient because of the 5 sub-queries located in the `SELECT` block. Once your database starts growing then the calls to this query will feel as fast as molasses. I definitely recommend a PHP loop to display the data as needed.

Comment: That's just what i was thinking. I'll try to implement that code right now. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the answer, but to avoid subqueries...

```
SELECT idmtpersonalr, 
       MAX(IF(hora=11,IF(indicador='S','X',IF(indicador='N','-','')),'')) `11`,
       MAX(IF(hora=12,IF(indicador='S','X',IF(indicador='N','-','')),'')) `12`,
       MAX(IF(hora=13,IF(indicador='S','X',IF(indicador='N','-','')),'')) `13`,
       MAX(IF(hora=14,IF(indicador='S','X',IF(indicador='N','-','')),'')) `14`,
       MAX(IF(hora=15,IF(indicador='S','X',IF(indicador='N','-','')),'')) `15`
FROM mt_reporteradial
/*WHERE fecha='2014-02-10'*/
GROUP BY idmtpersonalr
ORDER BY idmtpersonalr
```